# I get the cannot get /path error in react application after i run build. how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[here's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGuo0.png)
Also I have set a button with onClick="Refresh", I get this after clicking it. in development server it worked just fine but after build, it doesn't.
I feel like I've made a rookie mistake but I have no idea what it might be, also I have to solve it in two days max... I would really appreciate your help, thanks!

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Guide from "./components/Guide/Guide";
import Test1 from "./components/Test1/Test1";
import Test2 from "./components/Test2/Test2";
import Test3 from "./components/Test3/Test3";
import Auth from "./components/Auth/Auth";
import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import Login from "./components/Auth/Login/Login";
import PostRegister from "./components/Auth/PostRegister/PostRegister";
import PreTest from "./components/PreTest/Pretest";
import Result from "./components/Result/Result";
import PasswordReset from "./components/Auth/PasswordReset/PasswordReset";
import ResultHelp from './components/Result/ResultHelp';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Guide} />
          <Route path="/auth" component={Auth} />
          <Route path="/passwordreset" exact component={PasswordReset}/>
          <Route path="/postregister" exact component={PostRegister} />
          <Route path="/pretest" exact component={PreTest} />
          <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/test1" exact component={Test1} />
          <Route path="/test2" exact component={Test2} />
          <Route path="/test3" exact component={Test3} />
          <Route path="/result" exact component={Result} />
          <Route path="/resulthelp" exact component={ResultHelp}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here's my main App.js:

I have used `<BrowserRouter>` as wrapper for app.js and the whole application routing is handled by react-router.

Comment: Add your App.js file to the Post , so that we may see the issue

Comment: @Parsa Badri is your other routing working in production? can you post your Auth component here?

Comment: No, the whole routing does not work. Looks like all the http get requests need to be handled from a root url which is index.html but I have no idea how to do it.